# Django: Combine two similar util functions

Tags: python, django

I have the following get function in my `views.py`. My two until functions do almost look the same and I don't seem to follow the DRY principle. However, I currently don't know how to write this better. Can you suggest a better way?

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Delete discount code cookie if ?delete_discout is set in get parameter
    delete_discount_code = request.GET.get('delete_discount')
    if delete_discount_code:
        self.discount_code = delete_discount_session(request, self.discount_code_session)

    # Delete discount code cookie if ?delete_social_ticketing is set in get parameter
    delete_social_ticketing = request.GET.get('delete_social_ticketing')
    if delete_social_ticketing:
        self.social_ticketing_code = delete_social_ticketing_session(request, self.social_ticketing_session)
```

My utils.py are structured like this:

```
def discount_cookie_name(event):
    """Unique discount cookie name per event"""
    return f'discount_code_{str(event.pk)}'

def social_ticketing_cookie_name(event):
    """Unique social ticketing cookie name per event"""
    return f'social_ticketing_{str(event.pk)}'

def delete_social_ticketing_session(request, social_ticketing_code_session):
            if social_ticketing_code_session:
                del request.session[social_ticketing_cookie_name(request.event)]
                return None

def delete_discount_session(request, discount_code_session):
    if discount_code_session:
        del request.session[discount_cookie_name(request.event)]
        return None
```

Comment: Do have a roughly idea in mind, hope it'll help.
basically, the two sessions can be combined as one, you do not need to write if it's a social ticketing or discount.  If you are thinking of getting the session name, you can pass an extra field for the delete function to determine which name to get

Comment: Similarly, you can use a dictionary to store the session info. For example, {'discount': 0, 'social_ticketing': 0} and loop over all the keys with 'delete' in them to delete everything.

Comment: this code does not work at all but just giving you an idea of what I meant https://pastebin.com/1nSZvB5K basically try treating two functions as one, don't let the wordings trick you as it does that sometimes.  treating them as one then think of something to easily differential them inside the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a couple of issues:

Lines like:

```
self.discount_code = delete_discount_session(request, self.discount_code_session)
```

could be written as:

```
delete_discount_session(request, self.discount_code_session)
```

since `delete_discount_session` and `delete_social_ticketing_session` will always return `None`

On the other hand, `delete_discount_session` will be always deleting the a `dicount` coockie, the same for `delete_social_ticketing_session` it will be always deleting a `social_tiketing` cookie, so, you can make the name resolution right there:

```
def delete_social_ticketing_session(request, social_ticketing_code_session):
    if social_ticketing_code_session:
        del request.session[f'social_ticketing_{str(request.event.pk)}']

def delete_discount_session(request, discount_code_session):
    if discount_code_session:
        del request.session[f'discount_code_{str(request.event.pk)}']
```

And then you have that the only differences are the names of the condition variable and the name of the cookie so:

```
def delete_cookie(request, cookie_prefix, condition):
    if condition:
        del request.session[f'{cookie_prefix}_{str(request.event.pk)}']
```

With all that in place you could just write:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Delete discount code cookie if ?delete_discout is set in get parameter
    if request.GET.get('delete_discount'):
        self.delete_cookie(request, 'discount_code', self.discount_code_session)

    # Delete discount code cookie if ?delete_social_ticketing is set in get parameter
    if request.GET.get('delete_social_ticketing'):
        self.delete_cookie(request, 'social_ticketing', self.social_ticketing_session)
```